# How to handle concurrent users making changes to data in Blazor webassembly

Tags: c#, blazor

My current understanding of Blazor webassembly is that the user loads an app, makes one initial call into a web API and retrieves the data set to be displayed. The user can then interact with the data locally and only make calls into the API whenever the user inserts, updates or deletes items. Further "Get" calls aren't necessary beyond the initial call because the state of the data is loaded locally.

What if several concurrent users are expected to interact with the same data set? Traditionally, in a standard web app, external changes to the data set would be visible rather quickly whenever the page gets reloaded, and a fresh data set retrieved from the back-end storage. In some cases it can be desirable to introduce polling if the user is expected to sit on a page for a long time without reloads.

I'm not sure what is considered best practice in the Blazor world to handle this type of use case. Is polling of the web API an accepted solution? Should I be looking to SignalR to notify clients of changes in the dataset? Any built-in mechanism I've overlooked?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some research, the only standard, accepted way of doing this in Blazor Webassembly is to use [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor-webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).

Answer (score 2):

I dont think Blazor is any different from other frameworks in this respect. If you are editing an object on the browser, you have two choices:

1. Let each user edit and save without any coordination amongst the user. The object will be left in the state in which the last user saved it.
2. Implement some kind of object locking. I dont know if .NET Core provides this kind of thing but shouldn't be difficult to manage yourself. So in this scenario, if a user has checked out an object, no other user will be allowed to edit it till the checkout is returned. But I doubt this kind of strategy will work with general purpose apps. For the enterprise this may work. Issue would be someone closes his/her browser before returning the object. No other user will be able to access the object until you implement some kind of time out. Update: EF Core
   has concurrency detection and you can configure it to raise DbUpdateConcurrencyException. You can then use that to either overwrite changes made by another user or give an option to the user to reload new data etc.

On the question of refreshing the data, general practice seems to be getting data when a component is initialized, making changes and then saving it back. It would be rare that you would want to re-fetch in between, albeit you could as often as you wish. But that would also refresh the user interface again and again.